# eWallet.ts:84 You have tried to read "publicKey" on a WalletContext without providing one. Make sure to render a WalletProvider as an ancestor

Tags: solana-program, solana-wallet-adapter, wallet, phantom-wallet

[image]
import React, { FC, useMemo } from 'react';
import { ConnectionProvider, WalletProvider } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { WalletAdapterNetwork } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-base';
import { CoinbaseWalletAdapter, PhantomWalletAdapter, SlopeWalletAdapter,SolflareWalletAdapter, TorusWalletAdapter } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets';
import {
WalletModalProvider,

```
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui';
import { clusterApiUrl } from '@solana/web3.js';
import App from "./App"

// Default styles that can be overridden by your app
require('@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui/styles.css');

export const Wallet: FC = () => {
    // The network can be set to 'devnet', 'testnet', or 'mainnet-beta'.
    const network = WalletAdapterNetwork.Devnet;

    // You can also provide a custom RPC endpoint.
    const endpoint = useMemo(() => clusterApiUrl(network), [network]);

    const wallets = useMemo(
        () => [
        
            new PhantomWalletAdapter(), new CoinbaseWalletAdapter(),new SlopeWalletAdapter(), new
            TorusWalletAdapter(), new SolflareWalletAdapter({ network })
        ],
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
        [network]
    );

    return (
        <ConnectionProvider endpoint={endpoint}>
            <WalletProvider wallets={wallets} autoConnect>
                <WalletModalProvider>
                <App/>
                </WalletModalProvider>
            </WalletProvider>
        </ConnectionProvider>
    );
};
```

app.js
import "./App.css";
// import { useConnection, useWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import { WalletMultiButton } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui";
require("@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui/styles.css");
function App() {
// const { connection } = useConnection();
// const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet();
return (



);
}

export default App;